# Entity Framework Code First Customer and Address Registration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-model-first

one for `customer`, and one for `address`.

**Required Functionality** When a customer registers, they enter their personal details such as name, tel as well as their address details in the same view.

**Current Functionality**
At present, EF scaffolding provides a dropdown list of addresses to choose from.

**Current Code**

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [Required]

    ...
    Customer Fields
    ...

    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    ...
    Address Fields
    ...

    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual List<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
}
```

When seeding the database, I can do so as follows:

```
new List<Customer>
    {
        new Customer 
            { 
                ** Customer Fields ** , 
                Address = new Address { ** Address Fields ** }
            }
    }.ForEach(c => context.Customers.Add(c));
base.Seed(context);
```

**My thoughts**

My initial thoughts are that I should create a 3rd Data model called `CustomerWithAddress` which is essentially a composite of `customer` and `address` models. This would allow me to scaffold a strongly typed view.

Alternatively, is it possible for a controller to pass 2 models to 1 view?

I don't know if this is the best way of tackling this problem, or in fact if it is possible. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If your customer model has an address property, then you will be able to access it from your view. e.g.

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor(x => model.Address.Addressline1)
```

Your viewmodel Idea is a good one, but it's not necessary for this particular case.

EDIT: As my friend below pointed out, you may need to manually load the Address property if you are employing lazy loading.

Comment: This may require use of `.Include()` to actually load the `Address` property; if EF is lazy-loading things then `model.Address` may be null when it gets to the view.